# why mysql still use index to get data when use the 2nd col of multiple column index in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Why mysql still use index to get data when use the 2nd col of multiple column index  in mysql?
We know mysql use leftmost match rule, but here I didn't use the 1st col and I use the 2nd col, the two `select` operation results bellow show that mysql sometimes use index and sometimes didn't use it. Why? In addtion, my mysql version is 5.6.17.

1.create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_cid_INX` (`name`,`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

2.run `select`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM student WHERE   cid=1;
```

3. result:
[Result with index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTuYb.png)

It shows that mysql use index to get data.

The following is another table.

1.create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `NAME` (`name`),
  KEY `AGE` (`age`),
  KEY `LeftMostPreFix` (`name`,`address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

2.run `select`:

```
explain SELECT * FROM test.test_table where  address = '东京'
```

3.result：
[Result without index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfZn2.png)

On the contrary here it shows that mysql didn't use index to get data.

Comparing above two results, I feel puzzled why the 1st result use index which is **against leftmost match rule.**

Comment: It is always better not to paste code as images, but as actual code. A willing person could then try cutting/pasting it in different versions or whatnot. As is, that's not possible

Comment: Get it, thanks for your suggestion and I will pay attention to that. Thanks.

Comment: You could pay attention to that right now

Comment: I'm sorry for my wrong format just now and I've try my best to imporve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html)

> it is possible that key will name an index that is not present in the possible_keys value. This can happen if none of the possible_keys indexes are suitable for looking up rows, but all the columns selected by the query are columns of some other index. That is, the named index covers the selected columns, so although it is not used to determine which rows to retrieve, an index scan is more efficient than a data row scan.

So while there is a key used here, it's not actually used in the normal sense. In some situations it is still more efficient to use that as a table scan (in your first example), in others it might not be (in your second)

Most of the times these things are decided by the optimizer based on several things (usage of the table, etc).

Best thing to remember is that here you can NOT "use the index", and that's why there is no index in `possible keys`. You can only use the index if the first column is in there.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nanne.According to your answer, I've understood a little more and maybe the two examples are special. In the 1st `select` example, generally this kind of case can't use index because it's against leftmost match rule, but here optimizer find the key `name_cid_INX` (`name`,`address`)  just covers the selected columns (default include primary key?) in results so here it shows it use `name_cid_INX` key for efficiency. In the 2nd example, because the key can't cover the selected columns all so it didn't use (`name`,`address`) key. That is what I understand now. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not really sure that I understand your question to be honest. What happens in both version that it doesn't use the key in a traditional way: it never uses it for the lookup (the thing you would want). So in that sense these 2 queries are actually the same! It DOES use it to get some effeciency for the row scan, but bascially it means that you're not actually using that key that much. Bottomline is you need to create an index that has your used column as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Neither index in either Case starts with what is in the `WHERE`, so there will be a full scan of table or of index.

Case 1:  The index is "covering", so it is a tossup as to which (table scan vs index scan) is better.  The Optimizer happened to pick the secondary index.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` *may* have enough details to explain 'why' in *this* case.

Case 2:  Because of `*` (in `SELECT *`), the secondary index is at a disadvantage -- it is not "covering", so the processing will bounce back and forth between the index and the data.  So it is clearly better to simply scan the table.

Instead of trying to understand EXPLAIN (in these cases), turn the question around: "What is the optimal index for this query against this table?" Then follow the guidelines [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).